# Google Drive API 1.4 error : Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am using Below piece of code to get files with service account.

```
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2("D:\\05-privatekey.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        var privateKey = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
        var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)
        {
            ServiceAccountId = "877564787679-glrhdp0gclc9mbj77qe4998dkc6mfj62@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
            Scope = DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue(),
            ServiceAccountUser = "user1@05.mygbiz.com"
        };
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);
        DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            Authenticator = auth,
            ApplicationName = "My APP",
        });

        FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
        FileList files = request.Execute();
```

Here Execute() api is giving exception

> *Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the
>   response.*

Edit: Project is based on the settings mentioned @ https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Build

Edit 2: I have proper settings in CPanel based on service account

Comment: Did you go through the delegation that's explained on https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation?

Comment: Thanks Burcu,
It starts working....
I have created a new Google APP account and did the setting mentioned @ https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation....But I think It takes some time to take effect....:-)

Comment: Hi @Jeevan I am also trying to do the same.But every time they want authentication.Can you please help me in that.My mail id amit.ghosh@live.com. Can you please share your code with me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  I got it working eventually; I had a few things wrong.

1. I went to the [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) and regenerated and downloaded my key file.  Go to APIs & auth->Registered Apps.
2. The ONLY properties I put in the `provider` object are `.ServiceAccountId` and `.Scope`.
3. I had to replace `Scope` with the actual scope and not use the enum value (This is only a problem because I am using VB).  I'm working in Fusion Tables and the scope was rendering as just "Fusiontables" because VB.NET does not use the `GetStringValue()` enum function.  Now I'm using `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables"`.  Go [here](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) for a list of valid scopes.
4. For the `ServiceAccountId`, I used the service account "Email address:" with the "@" in it. (12345@developer.gserviceaccount.com), and not the one they label as a "Client ID:" in the console (12345.apps.googleusercontent.com).

Hopefully this helps others.